# Where to look for the parameter passed in action generators in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this piece of action generator in one of the files of actions where I see that an object has been passed to the action generator XYZ. I can't copy paste code from the codebase of the place where I work. Where should I look for this object and where is it coming from? Being a newbie to redux, I find it bit difficult to get this thing.

```
export default xyz = (options = {}) => {

}
```

I checked mapdispatchtoprops and I see something similar.

```
xyz: (options = {}) => {
            dispatch(
                xyz(options)
            );
        },
```

I still could not get my head around the flow of data in redux in this case.

Comment: look for where the action is implemented. Depending on your team's approach it could be in a variety of locations. It's not magic - the action params have to get passed in somewhere. Just a bit fiddly to track them down.

It might help you to have a bit of a look at the reducer too and see what's going on there. Could give you some clues about where to look for the params.

Comment: problem with this approach i.e passing everything in the `options` parameter is that it's hard to track down the type. Each action should have a `type` that corresponds to a switch statement in a `reducer`, this is normally how you would trace actions to their corresponding reducers when they have their type hardcoded in the action generator body. Just start by looking for calls like this `this.props.xyz(...)` so you can see what the type is - then look for reducers that check for that type

Comment: yes, I figured out the logic using the method that you stated above. They have asynchronous functions implemented as xyz and they are using options as payload .that's all i could get .